# Blender not exporting mesh properly

Tags: export

I have just started using blender 2.66a. I was trying to model a chair.
I used a cube to create the chair. I exported it as an .obj file. However when I tried to import it back in, it is just showing a cube instead of the chair which I had modeled.

**[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_I1H5C0EX4lUVM3LWI1V0tQYlk/edit)**

Comment: Exact problem but for another format, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5249/exported-dae-models-have-a-cube-embedded-in-them

Comment: I downloaded your file and tried it. It works fine for me, just make sure you exported the right cube (your scene has 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the cube instead of the chair is because there is a Cube on layer `1`. Your chair is on layer `3`. You only had layer `3` visible which is why you did not see the cube even though it is there.

There are two ways to avoid this problem in the future:

## Method 1 - deleting the cube

1. Go to layer 1 by pressing `1` on your keyboard
2. Select the cube and delete it, <kbd>X</kbd>

## Method 2 - only exporting the needed meshes

1. Select the chair and any other items you wish to export
2. In the export dialog check *Selection Only*

   [image]

Once you do this you can import the chair and it will work like you expect it to.